# Class variable and __dict__

Tags: python

Why `print(b.__dict__)` prints`{'state': 'Init'}` I understand, but why does `print(b._di)` print`{'state': 'Init'}`?

```
class A:
    _di = {}
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._di


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.state = "Init"


b = B()
print(b.__dict__) # {'state': 'Init'}
print(b._di) # {'state': 'Init'}
```

Comment: `self.__dict__ = self._di` assigns the **reference** to the same dictionary referred by `self._di` to `self.__dict__`.

Comment: Related: [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/11082165)

Comment: because `b.__dict__` and `b._di` *are the same object*, because of `self.__dict__ = self._di`.

Comment: Here's a classic that everyone using python should know and understand: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html